# Intuition for right-hand, left-hand limit existing, number of discontinuities is countable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

My real analysis book has the following proposition.

> **Proposition.** Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function. Then both $\lim_{y \to x+} f(y)$ and $\lim_{y \to x-} f(y)$ exist for every $x$. Moreover the set of $x$ where $f$ is not continuous is countable.

The proof it gives is as follows.

> Let $f$ be an increasing function and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. The collection of real numbers $A = \{f(x): x < x_0\}$ will be bounded above by $f(x_0)$ since $f$ is increasing. let $M = \sup_A f(x)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $M$ is the least upper bound of $A$, then $M - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound; therefore there exists $x_1 < x_0$ such that $f(x_1) > M - \epsilon$. Let $\delta = x_0 - x_1$. If $x_0 - \delta < x < x_0$, then $f(x) \le M$ because $M$ is an upper bound, and $f(x) > M - \epsilon$ because $f(x) \ge f(x_1) > M - \epsilon$. This holds for each $\epsilon > 0$, and so $\lim_{x \to x_0+} f(x)$ exists.
>
> If $B$ is a subset of real numbers bounded below, then $A = \{-x : x \in B\}$ will be a collection of real numbers bounded above. If $M = \sup A$, then $-M = \inf B$. Therefore a subset of real numbers that is bounded below has an infimum. With this observation, we can imitate the proof above to see that $\lim_{x \to x_0+} f(x)$ exists.
>
> Finally, for each $f(x-) < f(x+)$ there is a rational number in the interval $(f(x-), f(x+))$. No two such intervals can intersect because $f$ is increasing, so the rational numbers corresponding to different intervals must be different, and we conclude that there can only be countably many $x$ such that $f(x-) \neq f(x+)$.

I can follow this proof step to step, but am still confused. I have a few questions.

1. What is the underlying intuition behind the proof?
2. What are the one to three key ideas this proof boils down to?
3. How can I best visualize this proof geometrically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first key idea is that if a set of real numbers is bounded above (below, resp.), then it has a least upper bound (greatest lower bound, resp.); it is this that ensures that the one-sided limits exist.

Then we observe that $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$ if and only if

$$\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)<\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)\;,$$

so that to each point $x_0$ of discontinuity of $f$ we can assign an open interval

$$I(x_0)=\left(\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x),\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)\right)$$

in $\Bbb R$.

The next key point is that because $f$ is non-decreasing, these intervals $I(x_0)$ must be pairwise disjoint: if $x_0$ and $x_1$ are both points of discontinuity of $f$, and $x_0<x_1$, then $I(x_0)<I(x_1)$, in the sense that if $u\in I(x_0$ and $v\in I(x_1)$, then $u<v$.

The final point is that every open interval must contain a rational number, and since the intervals are pairwise disjoint, no two can contain the same rational number, so there are at most as many of these intervals $I(x_0)$ as there are rational numbers. There are only countably many rational numbers, so there are only countably many of these intervals $I(x_0)$ and hence only countably many points of discontinuity of $f$.

The sketch below shows what could happen at one point $a$ of discontinuity. Here $L=\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$, $R=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$, and $I(a)$ is the open interval $(L,R)$, shown in red on the $y$-axis. The function value $f(a)$ could be anywhere in the closed interval $[L,R]$.

[image]

The sketch oversimplifies the situation in one important respect: it shows $f$ with no discontinuities near $a$. In fact $f$ could have jumps arbitrarily close to $a$. In the sketch below I’ve tried to suggest one of the simpler ways in which that could happen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The proof, in my opinion, boils down to these ideas:

1. For an increasing function we have $\lim_{x\uparrow x_0} f(x) = \sup_{x<x_0}f(x)$ and thus the limits always exist.
2. An increasing function can have only countably many discontinuities, because each discontinuity results in an interval and all these intervals have to be disjunct.